# How to convert recursive CTE to be usable in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion

I have a recursive CTE-query like this:

```
;WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   e.entryID ,
                    e.bOpen ,
                    e.nextEntryID ,
                    e.entryID AS OriginalentryID
           FROM     entries e
           WHERE    e.bOpen = 1
                    AND e.nextEntryID IS NOT NULL

           UNION ALL

           SELECT   e.entryID ,
                    e.bOpen ,
                    e.nextEntryID ,
                    c.OriginalentryID
           FROM     cte c
                    INNER JOIN entries e ON e.entryID = c.nextEntryID
         )
SELECT  c.entryID ,
        c.OriginalentryID
FROM    cte c
WHERE   bOpen = 0;
```

Would there be any way to realise this without `CTE` (i.e. for SQL Server 2000)?
Any hints/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: CTEs are "standard SQL". SQL Server 2000 is well behind the curve, and is no longer supported by MS, so your time would be better spent getting the server upgraded.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right of course. It's not like I still use SQL Server 2000; It was more for learning purposes

Comment: For standard SQL you would need to put the statement terminator `;` at the end of the statement and add the `recursive` keyword to the `with` part.

Comment: most probably use cursor or dynamic sql.though you should provide table structure and sample data.

Comment: For up to 32 levels of recursion you can have a table valued function that calls itself. Though procedural code with a loop and a temp table would probably be easier.

Answer (score 2):

For SQL 2000, you can create a table-function that mimics your CTE expression, using a temporary table and a `WHILE` loop to load it.

The main drawback is that you won't benefit from applying `WHERE` constraints before returning from the function, but it works if the hierarchy table is small. To lessen the amount of data read before the `WHERE` clauses apply, you can pass parameters to filter (see comment on code):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FnGetEntriesByRoot (@rootId AS BIGINT)
RETURNS @result TABLE (
  entryID           BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  bOpen             BIT,
  nextEntryID       BIGINT,
  OriginalentryID   BIGINT
)
AS BEGIN

  -- insert the "root" element
  INSERT @result(entryID, bOpen, nextEntryID, OriginalentryID)
  SELECT e.entryID, e.bOpen, e.nextEntryID, e.entryID
  FROM entries e
  WHERE e.bOpen = 1
  AND (e.entryID = @rootId OR @rootId IS NULL) -- (1) filter condition!
  AND e.nextEntryID IS NOT NULL;

  -- while new items are found, insert into the result table
  WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) BEGIN
    INSERT @result(entryID, bOpen, nextEntryID, OriginalentryID)
    SELECT e.entryID, e.bOpen, e.nextEntryID, c.OriginalentryID
    FROM @result  c
    JOIN entries  e ON (e.entryID = c.nextEntryID)
    WHERE e.entryID NOT IN (SELECT entryID FROM @result)
  END

  RETURN;
END;

SELECT c.entryID, c.OriginalentryID
FROM dbo.FnGetEntriesByRoot(NULL) c
WHERE c.bOpen = 0;
```