# I need a SQL Server 2000 compatible alternative to this CTE query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, common-table-expression

The following query joins several tables and then creates a column called `MODIFIEDDATETIME` which gets set to the most recent `MODIFIEDTIME` / `MODIFIEDDATE`.

`MODIFIEDTIME` is stored in seconds from midnight. I need to make this query work on a SQL Server 2000 and would like to have it be as simple as possible. Any ideas?

***EDIT - I'm trying to do this without using temp tables.

```
;with CTE as 
(
    select 
        MODIFIEDDATETIME = (select max(modified)
                            from (values (dateadd(second, cij.MODIFIEDTIME, cij.MODIFIEDDATE)),
                                         (dateadd(second, cn1.MODIFIEDTIME, cn1.MODIFIEDDATE)),
                                         (dateadd(second, st1.MODIFIEDTIME, st1.MODIFIEDDATE)),
                                         (dateadd(second, csg.MODIFIEDTIME, csg.MODIFIEDDATE)),
                                         (dateadd(second, slo.MODIFIEDTIME, slo.MODIFIEDDATE)),
                                         (dateadd(second, dsc.MODIFIEDTIME, dsc.MODIFIEDDATE)),
                                         (dateadd(second, cms.MODIFIEDTIME, cms.MODIFIEDDATE))) as dateList (modified))
    from 
        dbo.HeaderTable cij
    left join 
        dbo.COUNTY cn1 on cn1.COUNTYID = cij.COUNTYID
                       and cn1.COMPANYID = cij.COMPANYID
                       and cn1.STATEID = cij.STATEID
    left join 
        dbo.STATETABLE st1 on st1.STATEID = cij.STATEID
                           and st1.COMPANYID = cij.COMPANYID
                           and st1.COUNTRYID = cij.DLVCOUNTRY
    left join 
        dbo.CUSTGROUPTABLE csg on csg.CUSTGROUP = cij.CUSTGROUP
                               and csg.COMPANYID = cij.COMPANYID
    left join 
        dbo.SALESORIGINTABLE slo on slo.ORIGINID = cij.SALESORIGINID
                                 and slo.COMPANYID = cij.COMPANYID
    left join 
        dbo.DESTINATIONCODETABLE dsc on dsc.DESTINATIONCODEID = cij.DESTINATIONCODEID
                                     and dsc.COMPANYID = cij.COMPANYID
    left join 
        dbo.COMMISSIONSALESGROUPTABLE cms on cms.GROUPID = cij.SALESGROUP
                                          and cms.COMPANYID = cij.COMPANYID)
select *
from CTE;
```

Comment: Why are you still using sql 2000? It has been dead for a LONG time now.

Comment: Why is your comment completely irrelevant and a complete waste of time to even post?  Are you suggesting that there are no SQL Server 2000 instances currently in place and functioning for businesses?  Are you suggesting that the EDW that I'm building to replace such an implementation doesn't exist?  Are you bored?

Comment: I was asking why you haven't yet gotten rid of a database that has been out of official support for at least 6-7 years. Building new functionality in 2000 is like creating new applications in VB6. Sure people do it and those people should anticipate people asking them why they are doing it.

Comment: What you don't understand is that sometimes it's possible to get clients that are on old systems that you need to stage data from.  No one is building a SQL Server 2000 instance.  This one has been in place for over 15 years.

Comment: @Arthur Perhaps you can create a table function that mimics your CTE? See [How to convert recursive CTE to be usable in SQL Server 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21992312/5395709) for more details.

Comment: Then perhaps your initial comment could have stated that you are pulling data out of a legacy system for a client and they won't upgrade. That would have answered the question about why you need to build something new in 2000. For the question at hand this is kind nasty because you are trying to get the largest value across seven columns. I will see if I can cobble something together. Can you use a temp table or does this have be a single query?

Comment: It wasn't relevant to say that I was pulling data out of a legacy system because that's completely irrelevant to the question I'm trying to answer.  We are not able to use temp tables, it has to be a single query.  Thank you for any time you put into this.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move the cte to from as follows:

```
select * from 

(select MODIFIEDDATETIME = (   select max(modified)
                                  from (   values (dateadd(second, cij.MODIFIEDTIME, cij.MODIFIEDDATE))
                                                 ,(dateadd(second, cn1.MODIFIEDTIME, cn1.MODIFIEDDATE))
                                                 ,(dateadd(second, st1.MODIFIEDTIME, st1.MODIFIEDDATE))
                                                 ,(dateadd(second, csg.MODIFIEDTIME, csg.MODIFIEDDATE))
                                                 ,(dateadd(second, slo.MODIFIEDTIME, slo.MODIFIEDDATE))
                                                 ,(dateadd(second, dsc.MODIFIEDTIME, dsc.MODIFIEDDATE))
                                                 ,(dateadd(second, cms.MODIFIEDTIME, cms.MODIFIEDDATE))) as dateList (modified) )
    from dbo.HeaderTable                         cij
         left join dbo.COUNTY                    cn1 on cn1.COUNTYID          = cij.COUNTYID
                                                    and cn1.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
                                                    and cn1.STATEID           = cij.STATEID
         left join dbo.STATETABLE                st1 on st1.STATEID           = cij.STATEID
                                                    and st1.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
                                                    and st1.COUNTRYID         = cij.DLVCOUNTRY
         left join dbo.CUSTGROUPTABLE            csg on csg.CUSTGROUP         = cij.CUSTGROUP
                                                    and csg.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
         left join dbo.SALESORIGINTABLE          slo on slo.ORIGINID          = cij.SALESORIGINID
                                                    and slo.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
         left join dbo.DESTINATIONCODETABLE      dsc on dsc.DESTINATIONCODEID = cij.DESTINATIONCODEID
                                                    and dsc.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
         left join dbo.COMMISSIONSALESGROUPTABLE cms on cms.GROUPID           = cij.SALESGROUP
                                                    and cms.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID) as a
```

Comment: This isn't going to work on a 2000 instance. Table valued constructors were introduced in sql server 2005.

Comment: AFAICT the values constructor for derived tables isn't available in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: FYI:Dateadd is from 2008 onwards:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql

Comment: @TheGameiswar the documentation doesn't show anything older than 2008 anymore because they are no longer supported. But trust me dateadd has been around a lot longer than sql 2005.

Comment: Thanks for that info i remeber using dateadd on 2005 and its a surprise

Answer (score 0):

```
select (dateadd(second, cij.MODIFIEDTIME, cij.MODIFIEDDATE)) cijDate   -- add column name
,(dateadd(second, cn1.MODIFIEDTIME, cn1.MODIFIEDDATE)) cn1Date
 ,(dateadd(second, st1.MODIFIEDTIME, st1.MODIFIEDDATE))st1Date
 ,(dateadd(second, csg.MODIFIEDTIME, csg.MODIFIEDDATE))csgDate
 ,(dateadd(second, slo.MODIFIEDTIME, slo.MODIFIEDDATE))sloDate
 ,(dateadd(second, dsc.MODIFIEDTIME, dsc.MODIFIEDDATE))dscDate
,(dateadd(second, cms.MODIFIEDTIME, cms.MODIFIEDDATE))cmsDate
into #temp1
from dbo.HeaderTable                         cij
     left join dbo.COUNTY                    cn1 on cn1.COUNTYID          = cij.COUNTYID
                                                and cn1.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
                                                and cn1.STATEID           = cij.STATEID
     left join dbo.STATETABLE                st1 on st1.STATEID           = cij.STATEID
                                                and st1.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
                                                and st1.COUNTRYID         = cij.DLVCOUNTRY
     left join dbo.CUSTGROUPTABLE            csg on csg.CUSTGROUP         = cij.CUSTGROUP
                                                and csg.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.SALESORIGINTABLE          slo on slo.ORIGINID          = cij.SALESORIGINID
                                                and slo.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.DESTINATIONCODETABLE      dsc on dsc.DESTINATIONCODEID = cij.DESTINATIONCODEID
                                                and dsc.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.COMMISSIONSALESGROUPTABLE cms on cms.GROUPID           = cij.SALESGROUP
                                                and cms.COMPANYID         = cij.COMPANYID

 create table #temp2 (modified datetime)

 insert into #temp2
 select cijDate from  #temp1
 union all 
 select cn1Date  from  #temp1
 union all 
 select st1Date from  #temp1
 union all 
 select csgDate from  #temp1
 union all 
 select sloDate from  #temp1
 union all 
 select dscDate from  #temp1
 union all 
 select cmsDate from  #temp1

 select MAX( modified ) from #temp2
```

Comment: Sorry I should have specified, I'm trying to do this without using temp tables.  Is that possible?

Comment: yes :) , you have to write a case statement and find out the biggest number in select statement . AS you have 7 fields so it is going to be a long case statement with multiple possible combinations.

Comment: Should be fun.  I have 13 instances of a query like this I need to write.  Some of them have upwards of 20 sets of dates I need to consider.  Gross!

Answer (score 0):

@rahul-richhariya was correct.  I needed to create a bunch of nested cases...and it's pretty ugly.  Thanks y'all for helping.  Here it is.

```
select MODIFIEDDATETIME = case
                              when dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                               and dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) then dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                              else case
                                       when dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                        and dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) then dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                       else case
                                                when dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                 and dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) then dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                else case
                                                         when dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                          and dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) then dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                         else case
                                                                  when dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                   and dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) then dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                  else case
                                                                           when dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(chd.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cms.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cpm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(csg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(cst.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dim.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlm.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dlt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(dnc.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(itl.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pdg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(pyt.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ssp.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(tgh.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                            and dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) > dateadd(second, coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(vig.MODIFIEDDATE, '')) then dateadd(second, coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDTIME, ''), coalesce(ctg.MODIFIEDDATE, ''))
                                                                       end
                                                              end
                                                     end
                                            end
                                   end
                          end
from dbo.CUSTTABLE                           cst
     left join dbo.CUSTOMERGROUP             csg on csg.CUSTOMERGROUP       = cst.CUSTOMERGROUP
                                                and csg.COMPANYID           = cst.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.CASHDISCOUNT              chd on chd.CASHDISCOUNTCODE    = cst.CASHDISCOUNT
                                                and chd.COMPANYID           = cst.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.COMMISSIONSALESGROUPTABLE cms on cms.GROUPID             = cst.SALESGROUP
                                                and cms.COMPANYID           = cst.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.CUSTSTATISTICSGROUPTABLE  ctg on ctg.CUSTSTATISTICSGROUP = cst.STATISTICSGROUP
                                                and ctg.COMPANYID           = cst.COMPANYID
     left join dbo.CUSTPAYMMODETABLETABLE    cpm on cpm.PAYMMODE            = cst.PAYMMODE
                                                and cpm.COMPANYID           = cst.COMPANYID;
```